# How to pickle QStandardItem Objects

Tags: python, pyqt5, pickle, qstandarditem

I am trying to pickle QStandardItem objects of PyQt5,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QTreeView, QApplication, QMainWindow
import shelve

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

Level1 = QStandardItem("Level1")
Level2 = QStandardItem("Level2")
Level3 = QStandardItem("Level3")

Level1.appendRow(Level2)
Level2.appendRow(Level3)

dbs = shelve.open("dbs")
dbs["Level1"] = Level1
dbs.close()
```

but it report this error **TypeError: can't pickle QStandardItem objects**

Then I changed to code to :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QTreeView, QApplication, QMainWindow
import shelve

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class myStandardItem(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, *kargs):
        QStandardItem.__init__(self, *kargs)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__

Level1 = myStandardItem("Level1")
Level2 = myStandardItem("Level2")
Level3 = myStandardItem("Level3")

Level1.appendRow(Level2)
Level2.appendRow(Level3)

dbs = shelve.open("dbs")
dbs["Level1"] = Level1
dbs.close()


dbs_new = shelve.open("dbs")
Level1_new = dbs_new["Level1"]

if Level1.hasChildren() :
    print("Level 1 has children")

if Level1_new.hasChildren():
    print("Level 1 new has children")


dbs_new.close()
```

it can be pickled, but I load the picked object, it reports:

**RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type myStandardItem was never called**

what's wrong with the above code? How to pickle QstandardItem with children? and reload successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to pickle QStandardItems, they are fundamentally abstract representations of the model data, you'd need to correctly provide an item prototype (which is not always easy to correctly implement) and there could anyway problems for tree structures. If I were you, I'd think of a simple serialization (based on lists or other data models like json). In any case, have a look for "Python shelve Qt", there are some related references to other Qt objects you could try to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.
I am trying to convert data to QStandardItemModel so I can display them with QTreeView.
The original data is much large and it takes hours to convert them into QStandardItemModel.
So I want to pickle QStandardItem then I don't have to convert each time.   the orignal data is below, but it has over 15 million lines...
`aa/bb0
aa/bb1/cc1
aa/bb1/cc2/dd/ee/ff2
aa/bb1/cc2/dd/ee/ff3
aa/bb2/cc3/dd/ee/ff/gg`

Comment: That's an even more important reason to avoid using QStandardItemModel at all. I'd suggest you to look into pandas (I never used it, but from what I know it you should be able to create a model based on it) and create a custom model using QAbstractItemModel as base. I've to warn you, it won't be easy to get it, as tree (or "nested") structures are not immediate to recreate, but it might be the right choice, especially for raw data written like that: using pickling to serialize and unserialize QStandardItems instances on such simple data structures is definitely not fast nor reliable.